# What is Chameleon hat for?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

I got a secret hat "Chameleon hat".

[image]

I wonder what it is for.

I am confused between two possibilities:

1. Multiple Stack accounts
2. Change in Display picture

What is it for exactly?